# Thomson Exercise 2.12: Why is $p_i^2 = m_i^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

I'm just working on some problems from Thomsons Modern Particle Physics. I' having a hard time understanding the last step in this calculation:

[image]

The relativistic energy-momentum relation is $E^2 = m^2 + p^2$, if I'm not mistaken. But why is it here $m^2 = p^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the Minkowski square of a four-vector with the Euclidean square of a 3-vector, viz. $p^2_\text{them}:=E^2-p^2_\text{you}$ i.e. $p^2_\text{four}:=E^2-p^2_\text{three}$.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm used to 4-vectors written with indices, thats why I mistook them. Thank you!